# Can't debug .NET DLLs referenced by deployed Matlab code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have a .NET Visual Studio project that reference a Matlab compiled dll (lets call it `M.dll`, created using Matlab compiler and NET builder) which, in turn, references another c# dll (lets call it `C.dll`, created with C# in Visual Studio).

Now I would like to debug `C.dll` so I tried to attach Visual Studio to the main application but it don't load the symbols (even if pdb files are in the program folder of the main application).

Note that if I don't deploy my Matlab code, using Visual Studio I can attach to Matlab process to debug `C.dll`. The problem arises when I use my `M.dll` loading it in main project.

Is there someone that can help me? Thanks a lot in advance.